# How to clean up Neo4j database

Tags: neo4j

I'm a newbie on Neo4j DB, and I want to write a Java function to clean up all of stuff in Neo4j db like nodes, relations, index, label ... but don't have effecting solution.
In current, I must use 3 queries to call to Neo4j server:

+ delete nodes and relations
+ delete constraints
+ delete index

Does Neo4j support to do all of that in just 1 query statement? 
Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Google gives awesome suggestions, you should take a look ;) http://google.com

Comment: I already searched on google, but found no suitable solution for my issue. test-delete-db-extension-1.4.jar is add-on just using for testing. Is it safe to using in production?

Comment: Right now you have to use the 3 statements, there is not built in `drop database`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cleanly delete everything, just stop the db, drop the `data/graph.db` folder completely and restart Neo4j, so

```
bin/neo4j stop; rm -rf data/graph.db; bin/neo4j start
```

as a one line command to fulfill your needs.

Comment: Thank Stefan, but I want to write a Java function to run that job. And Neo4j is placed in another server, I just have right to access the server by using http end-point.\